# Incrementing a number based on its sign

Tags: python, python-2.7

In a project of mine, I have to implement a function that adds or subtracts 1 based on the number's sign. Something like this,

```
def func(num):
    if num > 0:
        return num + 1
    if num < 0:
        return num - 1
```

But this seems like a unnecessarily long implementation for such a simple behavior. Is there an easier way to accomplish this. Maybe a one-liner ?

Comment: func = lambda x: x + 1 if x > 0 else x - 1 if x < 0 else None

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
return  num + math.copysign(1, num)
```

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for actually, other answers were one liners as well, but my goal was actually to avoid conditionals. Thanks to you, and keksnicoh as well. I am going to accept this because of the small difference in times of posting.

Answer (score 3):

You can use math module here:

```
>>> from math import copysign
>>> a = -1
>>> a += copysign(1,a)
>>> a
-2.0
>>> a = 3
>>> a += copysign(1,a)
>>> a
4.0
```

Numpy also provides a sign function

```
import numpy as np
a = 5
a += np.sign(a)
6
```

Answer (score 1):

Could use lambda to write a one line function.

```
a = lambda x: x+1 if x < 0 else x-1
```

Call it by doing this:

```
print(a(5)) # This would return 4 as the value.
```

Comment: Not completely. You've forgotten about 0 (as the question author I guess)

Comment: The 0 input will never be the case, so it was intended.

Answer (score 0):

```
def func(num):
    if (num == 1):
        return 2
    elif (num == -1):
        return -2
    elif (num > 1):
        return 1 + func(num-1)
    else: 
        return -1 + func(num+1)
```

Can add an extra if check if 0 is an input to check for.

Comment: this won't be the fastest way, is not a one liner and is more complex then authors attempt, but I love it.